# MySql output parameters in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ado.net

I'm running the following code, that is meant to execute `SET @Param = 3;` line in MySql, and get Param value 3.

```
MySqlCommand setCommand = new MySqlCommand("SET @Param = 3;", connection);

MySqlParameter parameter = new MySqlParameter("Param", MySqlDbType.Int32);
parameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
setCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);

setCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Console.WriteLine("Parameter value: "+parameter.Value);
```

I'm quite new to MySql, but as far as I understood, the query `SET @Param = 3;` sets the @Param variable value to 3, and apart from my c# code it looks like it's working (in separate workbench). But when running my code it throws the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL = 3' at line 1
```

I believe that when trying to run this query `SET @Param = 3;` it tries to fill @Param parameter that is null, instead of getting it's value. I've declared parameters Direction as Output and added it to the setCommand command Parameters, but it seems like I'm doing something wrong.
I don't know where am I wrong, is it Direction issue, the @/?/none parameter declaration issue, or maybe it is MySqlDbType issue (as I'm not sure that MySqlDbType.Int32 corresponds to Int32 in C#)? Please advise.

Comment: `MySqlParameter parameter = new MySqlParameter("Param", MySqlDbType.Int32);` forced the library to treat `@Param` as a parameter, not as MySQL user-defined variable. You don't provide the value, hence NULL is inserted for it. You shouldn't create a parameter, but must execute `SELECT @Param;` after your query for to retrieve the value returned from your stored object.

Comment: Thanks, @Akina, I've been following MS SQL tutorial and tried to adapting it for MySQL. In tutorial it has been working, and given that I've encountered no major discrepancies between SqlClient and MySqlClient before, I thought it would work too. So I'm looking forward to check it in MS SQL, but in MySQL it seems like your explanation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It should be working in MS SQL, I've used it's tutorial and adapted it for MySql.
After some research I've found a similar reported issue. In MySql, it seems that Direction property of Parameter can't be Output if CommandType is Text - `@parameter`s wouldn't be output as intended. You can set this property though, it just wouldn't work. The resolution might be executing `SELECT @parameter;` after executing the main SET/UPDATE/etc. parametrized queries to get values, or creating Stored Procedures.

Reference: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/231